# Center google map using xml file

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have created a google map [following this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3) that loads markers and polylines from a xml file created from a mysql database. Everything works fine, and you can see an example of the map [at this page](http://rclouise.com/travelroute/testmap6.php). I have created a separate PHP script that extracts the latitude and longitude of the last location entered into the database. Here is the output of the xml file:

```
<lastmarker>
   <latlon lat="14.439290" lng="-60.882240"/>
</lastmarker>
```

I would like the map to automatically center on the last location entered. I have followed several suggestions found on this site, but can not seem to get the code right. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What does the code look like that you think _should_ center the map on the last point?  `map.setCenter(point);` (right after `polyline.setMap(map);`) doesn't work?

Comment: Wow! It was that simple! Thanks, that worked great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your download XML function, add:

```
map.setCenter(point);
```

(right after polyline.setMap(map);)

Explanation as your loop process the points in the polyline it uses "point" as an intermediate value, when the loop exits, it contains the last value read from the file.

Updated code:

```
  downloadUrl("genxml2.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML; //xmlParse(data);
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    var path = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
      var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
      path.push(point);
    }//finish loop

    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: path,
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });
    polyline.setMap(map);
    map.setCenter(point); 

    }); //end download url
```